# PS using Get-WinEvent with FilterXPath and datetime variables?

Tags: datetime, powershell, filtering, event-log

- I'm grabbing a handful of events from an event log in chronological order
- don't want to pipe to *Where*
- want to use **get-winevent**

After I get the Event1, I need to get the 1st instance of another event that occurs some unknown amount of time *after* Event1. then grab Event3 that occurs sometime after Event2 etc.

Basically starting with:

```
$filterXML = @'
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="System">
    <Select Path="System">*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-General'] and (Level=4 or Level=0) and (EventID=12)]]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
'@    
$event1=(Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $PCname -MaxEvents 1 -FilterXml $filterXML).timecreated
```

Give me the datetime of Event1.
Then I want to do something like:

Get-WinEvent -LogName "System" -MaxEvents 1 -FilterXPath "*[EventData[Data = 'Windows Management Instrumentation' and **TimeCreated -gt $event1**]]"

Obviously the timecreated part bolded there doesn't work but I hope you get what I'm trying to do. any help?

---

I think perhaps filterhashtable is how I need to go? looking for clarification:

```
$Event2=(Get-WinEvent -Oldest -MaxEvents 1 -FilterHashtable @{logname="system"; providername="Microsoft-Windows-GroupPolicy"; starttime=$Event1}).TimeCreated
```

Comment: * what's wrong with `where-object`?

Comment: significantly slower. especially when going through a large security log

Comment: @ScottWeinstein Also, potentially incorrect. If you specify MaxEvents to Get-WinEvent, you're getting the first N unfiltered events, and then filtering those N events in the powershell pipeline. This is different than getting N events from the full scope of the event log that all match the filter.

Answer (score 6):

This is what you want ...

```
$t = (((Get-WinEvent -ComputerName $PCname -MaxEvents 1 -FilterXml $filterXML).TimeCreated).ToUniversalTime()).ToString("s")
```

As an aside, I need the time the computer started, so did something like this ...

```
$t1 = (((Get-WinEvent -ComputerName "myhostname" -LogName "System" -MaxEvents 1 -FilterXPath "*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-General']][EventID=12]]").TimeCreated).ToUniversalTime()).ToString("s")
```

OR

```
$t1 = (($boottime.ConvertToDateTime($boottime.LastBootUpTime)).ToUniversalTime()).ToString("s")
```

THEN

```
(Get-WinEvent -ComputerName "myhostname" -LogName "Application" -MaxEvents 1 -FilterXPath "*[System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime>'$t1']][EventID=6005]][EventData[Data='Sens' and Data='Logoff']]")|fl
```

OR

```
(Get-WinEvent -ComputerName "myhostname" -LogName "Application" -MaxEvents 1 -FilterXPath "*[System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime>'$t1']][EventID=6005]][EventData[Data='Sens' and Data='Logoff']]").Count
```

Answer (score 6):

It is not necessary to jam everything onto one line:

```
$t1 = [datetime]::Today.AddDays(-1).ToUniversalTime().ToString('s')
$xpath = @"
    *[System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime>'$t1']]
     [EventID=4624]]
     [EventData[Data='Sens' and Data='Logoff']]
"@

Get-WinEvent -ComputerName myhostname -LogName Security -FilterXPath $xpath -MaxEvents 1
```